# отличия path конвертеров django python

Tags: python, django

Django файл приложения urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [   
    path('<var>/', views.something_var),
    path('<slug:var>/', views.something_slug),
    path('<path:var>/', views.something_path),
]
```

Друзья, подскажите в чем отличие трех конвертеров на примере. Насколько я понял, что первая строка использует по дефолту str. Slug тоже возвращает тип str, исключая некоторые символы. Зачем использовать slug, когда он является подмножеством str? Конвертер path вроде должен возвращать со слэшем (/), но если посмотреть в отладчике var из функции:

```py
def views.something_path (request, var):
  .
  .
```

то в var никаких (/) не обнаруживается (.

Answer (score 0):

В случае с конвертером path
`path('<path:var>/', views.something_path)`
var может содержать слэш

#### URL

```
path = "something/var"
```

#### Ссылка в шаблоне

```html
<a href="{% url 'some_view' path %}"></a>
```

и вьюха отреагирует на этот url, как на одну переменную.
Если вы для такого url установите конвертер str, Django вам выдаст ошибку.

```
Using the URLconf defined in *.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:var>/', views.something_path),
]
The current path, something/var, didn't match any of these.
```

Соттветственно, ваша переменная var (в вашем примере) не пишет слэш, потому что состоит из одной строки без слэшей)
И в ваших паттернах слэш не является частью шаблона url в саммой ссылке - он только содержится в паттерне